# reinitiating an exe program

Tags: cmd, exe

I have a script.exe program that works on many files in a directory and saves the output of each file in a different directory. This program shows a minor error message on screen (due to lack of a supporting file, and which can't be fixed) after each file processes. To remove the error and start the process again I have to press (Tab+Enter) and then (Ctrl+R), but as I have thousands of input files, I have to do it that many times.

I am wondering if there is any way to put those keys in whenever the program shows the error message ...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The macro utility [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) can be used to automate keystrokes. You can target the exact window you need to, e.g. by title text or contents or window handle properties like class name. It's also open source and been popular for long enough for there to be excellent documentation and very many example scripts to start from.

You could also do the same thing from any language with Win32 API bindings, like Perl, Python, or Ruby, but that would mostly be working at a lower level, and require familiarity with the many peculiarities of that old API. If you go that route, several [NirSoft](http://nirsoft.net/) utilities will be useful (like [WinLister](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/winlister.html)), which expose window properties. AutoHotkey has some of that built into its window inspector.